# M2M relationship or 2 FKs?

Tags: mysql, sql, django

Which of the following structures would be preferable:

```
# M2M
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

class Group(models.Model):
    ...
```

or -

```
# 2 FKs
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...

class Group(models.Models):
    ...

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Which would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can combine these 2 variants using [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) option

```
groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='GroupMember')
```

What do you mean by `better`? Usually you don't need to create intermediate model (except the case when you have to store [extra data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)).

`ManyToManyField` does his job perfectly, so don't write its functionality by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The two are essentially the same. When you do a M2M Django automatically creates a intermediary model, which is pretty much *exactly* like your `GroupMember` model. However, it also sets up some API hooks allowing you to access the `Group` model directly from the `UserProfile` model, without have to mess with the intermediary model.

You can get the same hooks added back by using `through` as @San4ez explains, but you've only made things more complicated. Creating a custom `through` model is only beneficial if you need to add additional fields to the relationship. Otherwise, stick with the default.

Long and short, #1 is better, only because it's exactly the same as #2, but simpler and with no extraneous code.